# Почему возвращается так много элементов

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Должно вывестись одно значение переменной fuelLevelSensor , но выводится значения какого-то цикла

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      speed: 420,
      tank_capacity: 200,
      tank: 80,
      fuelLevelSensor: 0,
      items: [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    tankFilling() {
      tempCapacity = this.tank_capacity / 10;
      while (tempCapacity < this.tank) {
        this.fuelLevelSensor++;
        tempCapacity += this.tank_capacity / 10;
      }
      console.log(this.fuelLevelSensor);
      return this.fuelLevelSensor;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@import './source/variables.scss';
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,200,300,regular,500,600,700,800,900,100italic,200italic,300italic,italic,500italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,900italic);

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.wrapp {
   position: absolute;
   width: get-vh(270px);
   height: get-vh(231px);
   &>.background {
      position: relative;
      width: get-vh(270px);
      height: get-vh(231px);
   }
   &>.tachometer{
      position: relative;
      top: get-vh(-225px);
      left: get-vh(12.5px);
      width: get-vh(200px);
      height: get-vh(200px);
      border: get-vh(22px) solid white;
      border-bottom-color: transparent;
      border-radius: 100%;
      opacity: 0.4;
   }
   &>.kilomiter{
      position: relative;
      top: get-vh(-420px);
      font-family: 'Montserrat';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: get-vh(16px);
      line-height: get-vh(20px);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: center;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
   }
   &>.speed {
      position: relative;
      top: get-vh(-420px);
      font-family: 'Montserrat';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: get-vh(80px);
      line-height: get-vh(98px);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: center;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
   }
   &>.foot {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      top: get-vh(-410px);
      &>.footr {
         font-family: 'Montserrat';
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight: 500;
         font-size: get-vh(32px);
         line-height: get-vh(39px);
         color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      }
      &>.footfuelbars {
         display: flex;
         margin-right: get-vh(-15px);
         width: get-vh(22.5px);
         height: get-vh(4.5px);
         background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
         border-radius: get-vh(2.5px);
         transform: rotate(-90deg);
      }
      &>.footfuel {
         margin-left: get-vh(15px);
         width: get-vh(20.69px);
         height: get-vh(22.17px);
      }
   } 
}


body {
   background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
      <div class="wrapp" onselectstart="return false" onmousedown="return false">
         <div class="tachometer"></div>
         <div class="kilomiter">km/h</div>
         <div class="speed">{{speed}}</div>
         <div class="foot" v-if="tankFilling()">
            <div class="footr">R</div>
            <div class="footfuelbars" 
               v-for="(item, index) in items" 
               v-bind:style="index < 10 ? { background: `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)` } : {}">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: так у вас тут и есть цикл `v-for="(item, index) in items"`

Comment: Так я же вроде бы его перед циклом вызываю

Comment: Убрал цикл , также вызываются 300 чисел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу что 300 чисел, ошибка кроется тут `this.fuelLevelSensor++;`

Запишите например так:

```
tankFilling() {

        let tempCapacity = this.tank_capacity / 10;
        let a = this.fuelLevelSensor

        while (tempCapacity < this.tank){
            a++
            tempCapacity+=this.tank_capacity / 10
            console.log(tempCapacity)
        }
        return a
    }
```